# java (eclipse): the literal of type int is out of range (but I set it as a long)

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse gives me this error message: **The literal [number] of type *int* is out of range.** I know that's impossible to define an *int* with a number which is higher than  2147483647 or lower than -2147483647. The numbers which I want to set as an *int* are mobile phone numbers (in Switzerland they can have maximum the value of 0999999999 - *Isn't this already enough low to define it as an int??*). 
I changed the variable type of the attributes *date* and *number* in the class *Person* to *long*. Now I receive the error message which I mentionned above. Why? How can I fix this?

Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
public class PhoneBook {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Person sister = new Person ();
            Person brother = new Person();
            Person mother = new Person();
            Person father = new Person();

            mother.name = "Gertrud";
            mother.date = 12041969;
            mother.number = 0792467286;

            sister.name = "Theresa";
            sister.date = 02112002;
            sister.number = 0794567843;

            brother.name = "Megnitz";
            brother.date = 01041999;
            brother.number = 0775685421;

            father.name = "Randolph";
            father.date = 21071966;
            father.number = 0764532178;


    }

}

___________________________________________________________________________________________________



public class Person {

    String name;
    long date;
    long number;

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name + ", " + "born on " + date + " / " + number);
    }

}
```

Comment: Phone numbers need to be strings, not numbers. A long literal should end in L. Never put an extra 0 at the start of an integral literal, because that indicates the number is in octal.

Comment: If you need any convincing of why you shouldn't record a number as an int (with a leading zero), try printing `mother.number`.

Comment: Phone numbers, like *so many* simple, everyday things (e.g. dates and times, addresses, names...), are *stupidly* complicated. Do yourself a favour by using a library: [here is Google's](https://github.com/google/libphonenumber), but others are available too.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. The thing with the *octal* is clear now. This is an assignment for school, so I have to use int for the phone numbers. But it makes sense to use String.

Comment: Don't save phone numbers in number format (long, int, ect) because you will lose phone numbers when the first digit is zero. Change the telephone number type to String.